# Getting data from Google Fit to Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-fit, google-fitness-api

I am trying to merge all my fitness and health data a google sheet. I have achived getting everything in to the Google Fit app (activites, steps, weight, sleep, heart rate, calories expendede, calories consumed), and am now in the stage of getting all of these metrics in to a Google Sheet.

I have calories expended, weight, steps, heart rate in place, but I also need Calories consumed/daily result and the sleep data, which I am not capabale of coding myself. Anyone have any tips of what code I should add to get calories consumed (or daily result which would also be OK) and the sleep data?

Here is the google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vaWH6Rmfy3Y9HI55v85HSruLrGUHdJSwvOdWVdBs6_8/edit#gid=1921513373

Here is my current code:

```html
// add your Google API Project OAuth client ID and client secret here
var ClientID = '561647796011-0u3j8sudft2ga16u0f771v3p6g6v4eh7.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var ClientSecret = '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';

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Google Fit')
      .addItem('Authorize if needed (does nothing if already authorized)', 'showSidebar')
      .addItem('Get Metrics for Yesterday', 'getMetrics')
      .addItem('Get Metrics for past 60 days', 'getHistory')
      .addItem('Reset Settings', 'clearProps')
      .addToUi();
}

function getMetrics() {
  getMetricsForDays(0, 0, 'Metrics');
}

function getHistory() {
  getMetricsForDays(1, 60, 'History');
}

// see step count example at https://developers.google.com/fit/scenarios/read-daily-step-total
// adapted below to handle multiple metrics (steps, weight, distance), only logged if present for day
function getMetricsForDays(fromDaysAgo, toDaysAgo, tabName) {
  var start = new Date();
  start.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  start.setDate(start.getDate() - toDaysAgo);

  var end = new Date();
  end.setHours(23,59,59,999);
  end.setDate(end.getDate() - fromDaysAgo);
  
  var fitService = getFitService();
  
  var request = {
    "aggregateBy": [
      {
        "dataTypeName": "com.google.step_count.delta",
        "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps"
      },
      {
        "dataTypeName": "com.google.weight.summary",
        "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.weight:com.google.android.gms:merge_weight"
      },
      {
        "dataTypeName": "com.google.distance.delta",
        "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.distance.delta:com.google.android.gms:merge_distance_delta"
      },
      {

        "dataTypeName": "com.google.calories.expended",
         "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:merge_calories_expended"
      },
      {

        "dataTypeName" : "com.google.heart_minutes",
        "dataSourceId" : "derived:com.google.heart_minutes:com.google.android.gms:merge_heart_minutes"
      },
      {
        "dataTypeName": "com.google.active_minutes",
        "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.active_minutes:com.google.android.gms:merge_active_minutes"
      },
    ],
    "bucketByTime": { "durationMillis": 86400000 },
    "startTimeMillis": start.getTime(),
    "endTimeMillis": end.getTime()
  };
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + fitService.getAccessToken()
    },
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType' : 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(request, null, 2)
  });
  
  var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(tabName);
  
  for(var b = 0; b < json.bucket.length; b++) {
    // each bucket in our response should be a day
    var bucketDate = new Date(parseInt(json.bucket[b].startTimeMillis, 10));
    
var steps = -1;

var weight = -1;

var distance = -1;

var calories = -1;

var heartmin = -1;

var movemin = -1;

if (json.bucket[b].dataset[0].point.length > 0) {

steps = json.bucket[b].dataset[0].point[0].value[0].intVal;

}

if (json.bucket[b].dataset[1].point.length > 0) {

weight = json.bucket[b].dataset[1].point[0].value[0].fpVal;

}

if (json.bucket[b].dataset[2].point.length > 0) {

distance = json.bucket[b].dataset[2].point[0].value[0].fpVal;

}

if (json.bucket[b].dataset[3].point.length > 0) {

calories = json.bucket[b].dataset[3].point[0].value[0].fpVal;

}

if (json.bucket[b].dataset[4].point.length > 0) {

heartmin = json.bucket[b].dataset[4].point[0].value[0].fpVal;

}

if (json.bucket[b].dataset[5].point.length > 0) {

movemin = json.bucket[b].dataset[5].point[0].value[0].fpVal;

}

sheet.appendRow([bucketDate,

steps == -1 ? ' ' : steps,

weight == -1 ? ' ' : weight,

distance == -1 ? ' ' : distance,

calories == -1 ? ' ' : calories,

heartmin == -1 ? ' ' : heartmin,

movemin == -1 ? ' ' : movemin ]);

}
}

// functions below adapted from Google OAuth example at https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2

function getFitService() {
  // Create a new service with the given name. The name will be used when
  // persisting the authorized token, so ensure it is unique within the
  // scope of the property store.
  return OAuth2.createService('fit')

      // Set the endpoint URLs, which are the same for all Google services.
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

      // Set the client ID and secret, from the Google Developers Console.
      .setClientId(ClientID)
      .setClientSecret(ClientSecret)

      // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
      // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())

      // Set the scopes to request (space-separated for Google services).
      // see https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/authorization for a list of Google Fit scopes
      .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.read')

      // Below are Google-specific OAuth2 parameters.

      // Sets the login hint, which will prevent the account chooser screen
      // from being shown to users logged in with multiple accounts.
      .setParam('login_hint', Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())

      // Requests offline access.
      .setParam('access_type', 'offline')

      // Forces the approval prompt every time. This is useful for testing,
      // but not desirable in a production application.
      //.setParam('approval_prompt', 'force');
}

function showSidebar() {
  var fitService = getFitService();
  if (!fitService.hasAccess()) {
    var authorizationUrl = fitService.getAuthorizationUrl();
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplate(
        '<a href="<?= authorizationUrl ?>" target="_blank">Authorize</a>. ' +
        'Close this after you have finished.');
    template.authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl;
    var page = template.evaluate();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(page);
  } else {
  // ...
  }
}

function authCallback(request) {
  var fitService = getFitService();
  var isAuthorized = fitService.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this tab.');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab');
  }
}

function clearProps() {
  PropertiesService.getUserProperties().deleteAllProperties();
}
```